# FinderSync extension conflicts with Dropbox

Tags: objective-c, macos, dropbox, findersync

I have made a FinderSync extension, app but every folder monitored by Dropbox (to show the "Move to Dropbox" context menu) prevents my extension to show file badge icons inside that folder.
The folders I know Dropbox uses: ~/Dropbox, ~/Documents and ~/Desktop.

I read that the extension that gets enabled first takes the "ownership" of folder badge control.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: You could disable Dropbox extension, take "ownership", and enable it again. In any case, its not healthy to have a couple of FinderSync extensions in the same environment.

Comment: @Mugen that's a good idea but i still cannot monitor my home folder without messing up with ~/Dropbox badges

Comment: File bug at https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to restart DropBox Finder Integration on start of your app. This way your extension has higher priority for common folders. I'm issuing this bash command at start:

```
pluginkit -e ignore  -i com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon;
pluginkit -e use  -i com.yourcompany.yourextension;
pluginkit -e use  -i com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon;
```